# "I am sure what is going to happen next" is this grammatically correct?

Tags: grammar, word-usage, prepositions, questions

"I am sure what is going to happen next"

I have 2 questions **for** this sentence.

1. Was I supposed to say **I am sure *about* what...** with *about* or without it?
2. If we omit the "I am sure" part, the sentence will become a question. And it is confusing me, I don't know if I am saying the sentence right. Every time I use this type of structure, it reminds me of the rule *putting to-be verb at the end* in this type of sentences "Do you know who he **is**?". And I don't know what to do with *is" in the sentence above... Am I saying it right?
3. I said "I have 2 questions **for** this sentence"... is it **for** or **about** that I was supposed say?

Thanks for the answers. I really appreciate your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is a valid sentence, but it is clunky.

I would say: "I know what is going to happen next". That sentence is a cliffhanger, so anyone listening would likely want you to expand on **what** happens next.

3: *about*

Comment: "I know whats gonna happen next" is actually what I would say in spoken speech, but its the exact same sentence.